# Mapper gets null value for the field annotated with @JsonIgnore (resttemplate)

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I have a DTO that uses `@JsonIgnore` for the ID field, everything works fine. However, for testing purposes using `resttemplate`, ID is set to null after conversion of string to the DTO with the mapper. How to resolve this issue?

```
public class CarDTO {

    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;
    // there are more fields but not necessary to put all here

    @JsonProperty
    @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Here is the `resttemplate` call:

```
 @Test
 public void createACar() throws Exception {

    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
    CarDTO carDTO = getCarDTO("LL22222111");
    HttpEntity<CarDTO> entity = new HttpEntity<>(carDTO, headers);

    // Here the response has id with value
    ResponseEntity response = restTemplate.postForEntity(BASE_URI, entity, String.class);
    // But after conversion of string to carDTO id is set to null
    CarDTO carResponse = mapper.readValue(response.getBody().toString(), CarDTO.class);

    // Assertions ...
}
```

I commented out `@JsonIgnore` to make sure if it will work fine and it did.

Comment: I can't understand your question. What is "the mapper"? What are you trying to achieve? What are you doing, what do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specified :

```
@JsonIgnore
private Long id;

@JsonProperty
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
```

It means you enabled for Jackson the serialization (with the getter) and disabled the deserialization (with `@JsonIgnore` on the field)

In your test, this doesn't perform any JSON deserialization (just it stores the response body as a `String`) :

```
ResponseEntity response = restTemplate.postForEntity(BASE_URI, entity, String.class);
```

So it is expected that the id be not skipped in the body of the response object.
It reflects exactly what the servers returned as response.
But that performs a deserialization to `CarDTO`:

```
CarDTO carResponse = mapper.readValue(response.getBody().toString(), CarDTO.class);
```

So Jackson applies what you specified in the Jackson annotations of `CarDTO`:
If this field has to be deserialized, just remove this annotation.